# pytz: Why is normalize needed when converting between timezones?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I'm reading the not so complete [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and I'm stuck on understand one part of it.

> Converting between timezones also needs special attention. This also needs to use the normalize method to ensure the conversion is correct.

```
>>> utc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1143408899))
>>> utc_dt.strftime(fmt)
'2006-03-26 21:34:59 UTC+0000'
>>> au_tz = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
>>> au_dt = au_tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(au_tz))
>>> au_dt.strftime(fmt)
'2006-03-27 08:34:59 EST+1100'
>>> utc_dt2 = utc.normalize(au_dt.astimezone(utc))
>>> utc_dt2.strftime(fmt)
'2006-03-26 21:34:59 UTC+0000'
```

I tried this very example *without* using `normalize` and it turned out just the same. In my opinion this example doesn't really explain *why* we have to use `normalize` when converting between `datetime` objects in different timezones.

Would someone please give me an **example** (like the one above) where the result differs when not using `normalize`.

Thanks

Comment: see [Is normalize still needed when converting to local time zones?](https://answers.launchpad.net/pytz/+question/249229)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the pytz documentation:

> In addition, if you perform date arithmetic on local times that cross DST boundaries, the results may be in an incorrect timezone (ie. subtract 1 minute from 2002-10-27 1:00 EST and you get 2002-10-27 0:59 EST instead of the correct 2002-10-27 1:59 EDT). A normalize() method is provided to correct this. Unfortunately these issues cannot be resolved without modifying the Python datetime implementation.

Comment: this quote doesn't explain why would you need `tz.normalize()` after `.astimezone(tz)` call

Comment: [it is confirmed](https://answers.launchpad.net/pytz/+question/249229): *"When converting between timezones, `.astimezone()` should be all that is needed."* i.e., you don't need `tz.normalize()` after `.astimezone(tz)`.

Answer (score 6):

The docs say that normalize is used as a workaround for DST issues:

> In addition, if you perform date arithmetic on local times that cross DST boundaries, the results may be in an incorrect timezone (ie. subtract 1 minute from 2002-10-27 1:00 EST and you get 2002-10-27 0:59 EST instead of the correct 2002-10-27 1:59 EDT). A normalize() method is provided to correct this.

So it's used to correct some edge cases involving DST. If you're not using DST timezones (e.g. UTC) then it's not necessary to use normalize.

If you don't use it your conversion could potentially be one hour off under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yep, it's indeed a DST-related issue.

Comment: I don't think it's at all accurate to describe this as an edge case or even "only for DST".  Simply time-zones are horrifically complicated.  *Places* continually change their offset from UTC for reasons including DST and many other political reasons.  `normalize()` is used to ensure the correct offset is applied to the correct place and time.  See [one man's video rant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)