# Python - Setting a datetime in a specific timezone (without UTC conversions)

Tags: python, datetime, pst, pytz

Just to be clear, this is python 2.6, I am using pytz.

This is for an application that only deals with US timezones, I need to be able to anchor a date (today), and get a unix timestamp (epoch time) for 8pm and 11pm in PST only.

This is driving me crazy.

```
> pacific = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")

> datetime(2011,2,11,20,0,0,0,pacific)

datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 11, 20, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:0 STD>)

> datetime(2011,2,11,20,0,0,0,pacific).strftime("%s")
'1297454400'

zsh> date -d '@1297454400'    
Fri Feb 11 12:00:00 PST 2011
```

So, even though I am setting up a timezone, and creating the datetime *with* that time zone, it is still creating it as UTC and then converting it. This is more of a problem since UTC will be a day ahead when I am trying to do the calculations.

Is there an easy (or at least sensical) way to generate a timestamp for 8pm PST today?

(to be clear, I do understand the value of using UTC in most situations, like database timestamps, or for general storage. This is not one of those situations, I specifically need a timestamp for evening in PST, and UTC should not have to enter into it.)

Comment: What is the issue here - the end date you have is Fri Feb 11 12:00:00 PST 2011 and the start date is 11th Feb?

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to create a datetime for 8pm PST, and it is creating it for 8PM UTC and printing it as noon. I seriously just want to make an object for "8PM PST TODAY" and generate a unix timestamp, without having to do a bunch of UTC manipulations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-standard-lib

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a tzinfo object `utc` for the UTC time zone, then try this:

```
#XXX: WRONG (for any timezone with a non-fixed utc offset), DON'T DO IT
datetime(2011,2,11,20,0,0,0,pacific).astimezone(utc).strftime("%s")
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, putting the timezone into the `datetime` constructor isn't always robust. The preferred method using the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) would be:

```
pacific.localize(datetime(2011,2,11,20,0,0,0)).astimezone(utc).strftime("%s")
```

Also note from the comments that `strftime("%s")` isn't reliable, it *ignores* the time zone information (even UTC) and assumes the time zone of the system it's running on. It relies on an underlying C library implementation and doesn't work at all on some systems (e.g. Windows).

Comment: Actually, that only worked in the open interpreter I had, its now returning the wrong result once I moved it to script. Ill keep hammering away at it, though.

Comment: @liam, the time zone support in Python has always seemed half-baked to me. The problem in this case is that Unix/Linux dates are always UTC-based, even when displayed in your local time zone, and you need to adjust the Python date to be likewise.

Comment: Yeah, the issue was that I was running it in the interactive shell, and had already called tzset() (i think, i can't find the reference now), on PST. This did some screwy thing where PST was treated as UTC and screwed up all the pytz calculations. "Half-baked" is an understatement, I am amazed at how pointlessly confusing the datetime library is, considering how clean most of the built-in libraries are.

Comment: From pytz docs: """Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones."""

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian can you put the correct way if you're going to say both of the examples
 are `XXX: WRONG`?

Comment: @NickT sure. Here's [my answer from 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25664904/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I understand why my first example doesn't work, I've seen questions that provide ample evidence of that form breaking. But can you name a situation where the second one doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkRansom there is explicit comment: it fails for any local time zone with a non-zero utc offset.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just tried it, converting Pacific to Central, for dates both with DST and without DST. It worked perfectly. Do you have a *specific example*?

Comment: @MarkRansom run your code (the code in your answer) on any machine where the local time zone (`tzlocal.get_localzone()`) is not utc.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian As I said, I ran the conversion myself on my system which is in the US Central time zone. Unfortunately I couldn't include the `strftime` because my environment is Python 2.7 on Windows, which doesn't support `%s`. Is that the part which fails?

Comment: @MarkRansom: do you see `strftime('%s')`  in the code in your answer? Your code produces `1297504800` (`TZ=US/Central`). It should return `1297483200`.

Answer (score 26):

There are at least two issues:

1. you shouldn't pass a timezone with non-fixed UTC offset such as `"US/Pacific"` as tzinfo parameter directly. You should [use `pytz.timezone("US/Pacific").localize()` method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) instead
2. `.strftime('%s')` is not portable, [it ignores tzinfo](http://bugs.python.org/issue12750), and it always uses the local timezone. Use `datetime.timestamp()` or [its analogs on older Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279) instead.

To make a timezone-aware datetime in the given timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime 
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
aware = tz.localize(datetime(2011, 2, 11, 20), is_dst=None)
```

To get POSIX timestamp:

```
timestamp = (aware - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
```

(On Python 2.6, [see `totimestamp()` function on how to emulate `.total_seconds()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)).