# django datetimefield timezone

Tags: python, django, timezone

Ok, so I am reading a ton of posts about how it is a utc time and use pytz to convert the time so it is useful.  I can do all that, but it seems to be built into Django as on the admin page, if I create an entry with a datetimefield, it shows it as my time, saves it as utc and if I open it back up to edit, it shows it as my time again.  So my question is, how is the Django admin doing this?  I would rather do it that way than use another module.

Comment: Do you want to know the settings for the same or the code for how to do that?

Comment: I found the answer I needed here.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452555/converting-timezone-aware-datetime-to-local-time-in-python][1]  Exactly what I was looking for


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452555/converting-timezone-aware-datetime-to-local-time-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Django has a utc class that loads pytz.utc if pytz is installed and a custom UTC class when it is not.  You can use it for the tzinfo argument in a datetime object as shown below.

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
```

I also prefer not to add additional dependencies, but I've learned that pytz is one of those useful libraries that you will need sooner or later.  Now I just include it on on all my Django projects by default.

Comment: Thanks, I guess one more question, how would I convert the datetime object in utc returned by the model to say Central Time US?  Nothing I can find has been working for me.

Comment: Does this work https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone?

Comment: Yes, I found the localtime method, I thought it answered here but SO made it into a comment above, sorry.  Much appreciated though.  This is my first stab at Django.