# Django seems to be displaying datetimes in UTC format

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

In `settings.py` I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Singapore'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

If a user (who is living in Singapore) enters `2013-10-07 01:00 A.M.` in a form on my site, the value stored in my (PostgreSQL) database is `2013-10-07 01:00:00+08`.  When I pull up this information during a `python manage.py shell` session, I get `2013-10-06 17:00:00+00:00`.  The same happens when I try to render this information in a template.

What I think is happening: Django recognizes that the user is entering 1:00 A.M. on October 10th, Singapore time, and stores this in the database as `2013-10-07 01:00:00+08`.  However, when Django retrieves this info from the database, it formats it to UTC time, thereby giving `2013-10-06 17:00:00+00:00`.

Do I have that right?  And if so, what can I do to make Django display times using the same timezone information that is stored in the database (or at least using my `TIME_ZONE` setting)?  In other words, how can I make it so that the user sees the datetime in the exact same form as she entered it?

Answer (score 26):

I've figured out what's going on.  Based on what I had read in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates), I was assuming that with `USE_TZ=True`, Django would output datetimes in the current time zone (which defaults to the `TIME_ZONE` setting) *everywhere*--views, the shell, etc.

However, it turns out that Django *only* makes the conversion in templates, and even then only in the most direct, basic invocation of a `datetime` object.

Specifically, if you have an `object` with a `DateTimeField` and you render its `datetime` attribute in a template using `{{ object.datetime }}`, you will get a datetime converted to the current time zone.  Yay. However, this functionality won't work for *anything* else, even within templates, such as `{{ object.datetime.hour }}` (which will display the hour in UTC).  So it's basically just an invisible template tag.  Not as magical as I'd hoped!

It looks like I'll need to convert all datetimes to the current time zone in my views before passing them to my templates.  I find this kind of weird and counterintuitive considering that my database *already has* all of the datetimes stored in the time zone I want them displayed in.  Wouldn't it make more sense to have to explicitly tell Django you want database values expressed in UTC, than to have Django perform the work automatically and then make you change them back in your views?

**EDIT:** This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009299/1256700) on SO made the solution to my specific situation considerably easier:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

result = localtime(some_time_object)
```

**EDIT:** It turns out that only PostgreSQL stores time zone information, and that information is separate from the raw datetime values it stores, which are in UTC.  So I guess it makes sense for Django to render everything in UTC by default, since other database backends don't even store time zone info.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: if you generate an aware datetime which has a tzinfo object associated with it, then save it to Postgres, then retrieve it, the new datetime will be UTC-accurate but won't have the original tzinfo.  That means that if you compare the pre-save and saved datetimes with ==, it'll return True, but they aren't the same exact object since the timezones are different.

Comment: Mysql also allows storing timezone related info in field.

Comment: this is working solution, thank you for explaining question as most of the people suggest changing time zone which only affect template

Comment: you shouldn't deal with localization in your backend code. As explained in the Django docs, use UTC time in your DB objects, and time aware datetime objects in your code. Just for **displaying** them to the user with parts of that field (like the hour), you can use the `date` template filter: `{{ object.datetime|date:"H" }}` gives you the localized, correct hour.
As long as you  only use ONE timezone, and your app will NEVER support more than that, your solution works. But keep in mind that someday™ you will need it, and then it'll be hard... So try to make it right from the beginning...

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [`localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags) template tag

*update:
However that does refer to setting `USE_TZ` to `True` as you have*

Comment: Thanks for the response; I think I figured it out.  See my answer to my own question.