# django timezone is taken as UTC even though I have set it to 'Asia/Kolkata'

Tags: django, timezone

here is my timezone settings in settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = False
```

now when I use timezone.now(), I am getting UTC time always. Did I miss something

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to set `USE_TZ = True` to use the functionality.

Django converts the time to the specified timezone (`Asia/Kolkata`) only in `templates`. So, if you want to use your local time (`Asia/Kolkata`) somewhere in code (`views/models`) you have to use `localtime()` method. Follow the code to achieve it:

**settings.py**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_TZ = True
```

and,

```
from django.utils import timezone

my_local_time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Example in django shell

```
In [1]: from django.utils import timezone

In [2]: timezone.now()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 29, 14, 5, 30, 112218, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [3]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 29, 19, 35, 46, 649587, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
```

References:

1. [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134191/django-seems-to-be-displaying-datetimes-in-utc-format)
2. [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags)