# Django Timezone unaware DateTimeField Error

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Post model in my blog app as follows:

```
class Post(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    # ...
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField()
    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        print(self.publish) # printing publish date
        return reverse(
            'blog:post_detail',
            args=(
                self.publish.year,
                self.publish.month,
                self.publish.day,
                self.slug
            )
        )
```

In my settings.py, I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_TZ = True
```

I am using Django Admin to creat Post instances. Django Admin shows/displays correct time (local time, March 10). Printing of publish date in `get_absolute_url` method displays `2018-03-09 19:54:29+00:00` (March 9). This leads to generation of incorrect url causing errors when a post is accessed: `DoesNotExist at /blog/2018/3/9/third-blog-normal/`

Please help or provide hints to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the entry in urls that corresponds to `/blog/2018/3/9/third-blog-normal/`?

Comment: Have you looked at converting `self.publish` to [local time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009299/1558430) before turning the wrong date into a url?

Comment: It refers to a `Post` instance created on 2018/3/10.

Comment: @Brian, doing this works.  Converting self.publish to local time using `local_publish_date = localtime(self.publish)` and then passing year, moth and day to post_detail url.

Comment: Nice thanks, I guess I'll write a proper answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate absolute URLs based on the server's local time, the time that is fed into `get_absolute_url()` will simply have to be in its local timezone:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

class Post(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    # ...
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField()
    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        local_publish = localtime(self.publish)
        return reverse(
            'blog:post_detail',
            args=(
                local_publish.year,
                local_publish.month,
                local_publish.day,
                self.slug
            )
        )
```

The real lesson here is, despite what their names suggest, setting `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE` still [saves your datetimes in UTC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/). Whenever Django retrieves a datetime from the database, it will lose its timezone.