# Python date string manipulation based on timezone - DST

Tags: python, python-2.7, timezone

My objective is to take string(containg UTC date and time) as the input and convert it to local timezone based on Timezone difference. I have come up with the following code

**Code**

```
import time
print "Timezone Diff", time.timezone/3600

def convertTime(string):
        print "Before Conversion"
        print "year",string[0:4],"month",string[5:7],"day",string[8:10]
        print "hour",string[11:13],"min",string[14:16]
        print "After Conversion"
        print "newhour",int(string[11:13])-(time.timezone/3600)
        newhour = int(string[11:13])-(time.timezone/3600) 
        if newhour>=24:
            print "year",string[0:4],"month",string[5:7],"newday",int(string[8:10])+1
            print "hour",newhour-24,"min",string[14:16]
convertTime('2013:07:04:14:00')
```

**Output:**

```
Timezone Diff -10
Before Conversion
year 2013 month 07 day 04
hour 14 min 00
After Conversion
newhour 24
year 2013 month 07 newday 5
hour 0 min 00
```

This code is very basic , and clearly wouldn't work for month /year changes and not consider leap years. Can anyone suggest me a better approach to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) modules, using my timezone as an example:

```
import pytz
import datetime
s = '2013:07:04:14:00'
mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M')
mydate = mydate.replace(tzinfo=timezone('Australia/Sydney'))
print mydate
```

Prints:

```
2013-07-04 14:00:00+10:00
```

You may have to "reshape" the code to work for your exact output, but I hope this helps in any way!

Comment: ` import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz` can't import pytz

Comment: @misguided Yes, it's not part of the standard library. Take a look [here](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#installation) on how to download it. Or go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/), download the files, and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Mate is there a way for it to make it work on the standard system ?I can't download and install packages on my system. Sorry :(

Comment: @misguided There probably is a way with the datetime module (I linked the docs in my answer) but I don't know any method to do so. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Will try this on my home system to check if it works :)

Comment: @misguided Alright :). Just rememebr to change the `timezone('...')` to your local one :)

Comment: Still I don't have any other answers. I'll aceept this one as the most helpful :)

Comment: `.replace(tzinfo=..)` is incorrect way to convert a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC to the given pytz timezone. [Use `.astimezone()`, `.normalize()` as in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17704028/4279).

Answer (score 1):

To convert UTC time to a local timezone using only stdlib, you could use an intermediate timestamp value:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convertTime(timestring):
    utc_dt = datetime.strptime(timestring, '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M')
    timestamp = (utc_dt - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) # return datetime in local timezone
```

See [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287083/4279).

To support past dates that have different utc offsets, you might need `pytz`, `tzlocal` libraries (stdlib-only solution works fine on Ubuntu; `pytz`-based solution should also enable Windows support):

```
from datetime import datetime

import pytz # $ pip install pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

# get local timezone    
local_tz = get_localzone()

def convertTime(timestring):
    utc_dt = datetime.strptime(timestring, '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M')
    # return naive datetime object in local timezone
    local_dt = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
    #NOTE: .normalize might be unnecessary
    return local_tz.normalize(local_dt).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code sorted out the issue for me . Though `pytz` is probably the best approach to use. But in case you don't have pytz the below solution could be an alternative.

```
import datetime

    def convertTime(timestring):
        UTC_OFFSET_TIMEDELTA = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.now()
        local_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M")
        result_utc_datetime = local_datetime - UTC_OFFSET_TIMEDELTA
        print result_utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),

    s = '2013:07:07:14:00'

    convertTime(s)
```

Comment: your solution fails for past dates that have different utc offset (from the current one) due to DST or utc offset changes for other reasons.