# How does utcnow() work without time-zones?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am reading on SO that the Python standard library [does not define any time-zones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563487/2274357).

Also, from the Python 2.7 [datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> Note that no concrete tzinfo classes are supplied by the datetime module.

However, calling `utcnow()` generates the current time in UTC. Furthermore, Python can also provide the current local time with `now()`. I am assuming that this is only possible if Python "knows" the local time-to-UTC offset (in order to return the correct values).

But doesn't that mean that Python *is* timezone aware? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OS provides the current timezone, as well as UTC time.

The OS does *not*, however, provide other timezone info, such as when DST switches take place. In other words, you can get the *current* time in the UTC timezone, but not accurately calculate local time across the year, as the offset to UTC changes with the summertime and wintertime switches.

Comment: Okay I see. But I can't help but asking myself why doesn't the OS provide the additional timezone info? Are there any historical reasons for this? I don't understand why the OS is trusted to give the current time but not enough to give DSTs?

Comment: There are historical reasons, yes. No standards, the C API doesn't provide anything more than UTC vs local time (and the current and alternative offsets, if dst is active and a (very) ambiguous 3-letter code for the timezone).