# Flask + Jinja: Convert UTC to Local Timezone

Tags: python, flask, timezone, jinja2, pytz

I have a Flask app that stores a user's timezone (from `pytz.common_timezones`) in a database.

I store records in the DB using a UTC timestamp.

I want to display these records to end-users according to their timezone.

Is it best to:

1. Iterate through each record and convert the timezone before passing it to `render_template`?

   --or--
2. Define a macro within my view that performs this conversion within the template itself?

Are there any best practices for converting a naive timezone to a local timezone?

Comment: related: [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287083/4279) (it also shows `pytz` code example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two separate questions here.  The real question is about how best to manipulate your template - which could be asked about any value manipulation.  I'll let someone else answer on that.

With regard to the second question:

> Are there any best practices for converting a naive timezone to a local timezone?

That doesn't make a lot of sense.  "naive" in the python sense means "unaware of time zone" - so there's not really such a thing as a "naive timezone".

If you mean converting from a naive `datetime` to an aware `datetime`, then the best advice is to be sure to use the `localize` function, as described in [the pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).  Don't try to assign it to the `tzinfo` property yourself.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the second option is better since server code doesn't have to know the timezone information of each client. Also, flask extensions like [Flask-Moment](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Moment) make this much easier to be done.