# datetime, adding a day and getting correct format

Tags: python, datetime

There are various ways of adding a day for example:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

The problem with this is that the answer is: 2016-12-06 16:52:44.679431
I only need 2016-12-06. I can easily get that by performing a string manipulation like splitting. I as wondering if there was a way to do it directly.

secondly:

From what I have read from the documentation the below two ways should give me the time in my timezone neither do though.

```
import time
print(time.localtime())
```

result: time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=17, tm_min=50, tm_sec=56, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=340, tm_isdst=0)

&

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

return 2016-12-05 17:52:09.045170

neither do, they both give me GMT:

How do I get my local timezone?

Summary: 
Is there a direct way to a day and get the correct form? an
How do I get my local timezone?

Comment: well... i's not clear enough. Is your question about timezone or date foamting?

Comment: `(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date() == 2016-12-06`

Comment: It was about both but AChampion answered the formatting part

Comment: `datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)` -- uses `datetime.date.today()` rather than `datetime.datetime.today()`.  Result is local date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> datetime.date()
>
> Return date object with same year, month and day.

In your case:

```
import datetime

print("local hour: "+str((datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()))
print("utc hour: "+str((datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()))
```

Output:

```
local hour: 2016-12-06
utc hour: 2016-12-06
```

Another way is change `datetime.datetime.today()` to `datetime.date.today()`:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Output:

```
2016-12-06
```

Comment: Make sure to address all OP's questions: "Does datetime.now and datetime.today give you thet time in your time zone? Fro my previous code I am assuming it gives GMT so is there a direct way to change the timezone?"  Heck, I'll just answer.  The docs claim that that the time returned from `today()` and `now()` is local time.

Comment: the docs claim local time but I get GMT?? I read the docs before and that is why I am confused. Added examples to orginal q.

Comment: the  day component in local hour and UTC will be the same until about 9PM but the website I am building will definitely have a bug if the date and time I am using is GMT. –

Comment: @Tanc27:  Did the code that gave GMT run on your local computer or on the web server?

Comment: I'm using cloud 9 IDE. so  I guess they use GMT. I should have realized sorry. Do I just subtract five hours or can I change the timezone in my IDE?

Comment: Perhaps see [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-stand/13287083#13287083)