# Convert UTC time to local timezone in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert UTC time to local timezone (Asia/Calcutta).

Here is what i did:

`next_date_time` is a `datetime` format, `2019-07-11 13:12:14.240000`

```
    tz = self._context.get('tz')
    localtz = pytz.timezone(tz)
    local_date = localtz.localize(next_date_time)
    print'local_date',local_date
```

And the output is `2019-07-11 13:12:14.240000+05:30`. I can see the `+5:30` here. But i need the output like

```
2019-07-11 18:42:14.240000
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a python UTC datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-standard-lib)

Comment: @KbiR see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime

Comment: @Flo, Thanks, it worked.