# How to override a python3 __sub__ function so the data type isn't changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, subclass

I'm trying to subclass the datetime class so my main code looks cleaner.  However, doing any arithmetic on my subclass changes the data type back to datetime.datetime.

I took my original code and cut it down to a minimal example.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class worldtime(datetime):
   UTC = True
   tz_offset = timedelta(hours = 4)

   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      #kwargs['tzinfo'] = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
      return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

   def is_UTC(self):
      return self.UTC

   def to_local(self):
      print(f"type(self): {type(self)}")
      if self.UTC is True:
         self = self - self.tz_offset
         print(f"type(self): {type(self)}")
         self.UTC = False
         return self

dt = worldtime(2019, 8, 26, 12, 0, 0)
print (f"dt = {dt}   is_UTC(): {dt.is_UTC()}")
print (f"type(dt): {type(dt)}")
print (f"dir(dt): {dir(dt)}")
dt = dt.to_local()
```

The moment I subtract the tz_offset timedelta, the type of the object changes back to datetime.datetime:

```
dt = 2019-08-26 12:00:00   is_UTC(): True
type(dt): <class '__main__.worldtime'>
dir(dt): ['UTC', '__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', 
'__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', 
'__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
'__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime', 'date', 'day', 'dst', 'fold', 
'fromisoformat', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'hour', 'is_UTC', 
'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'max', 'microsecond', 'min', 
'minute', 'month', 'now', 'replace', 'resolution', 'second', 'strftime', 
'strptime', 'time', 'timestamp', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 'to_local', 
'today', 'toordinal', 'tz_offset', 'tzinfo', 'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 
'utcnow', 'utcoffset', 'utctimetuple', 'weekday', 'year']
type(self): <class '__main__.worldtime'>
type(self): <class 'datetime.datetime'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testwt.py", line 33, in <module>
    dt.to_local()
  File "testwt.py", line 27, in to_local
    self.UTC = False
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'UTC'
```

I can admit to being new to subclasses in python.  While I have seen other posts that seem to talk about this problem, there are no examples to follow.  The best I have seen is that I have to override the __sub__ operator, but I'm uncertain how to do that and ensure the returned object is the correct type.  Again, there aren't any clear code examples to work with...

Update: corrected a minor error in the example code because worldtime.to_local() needs to return the new instance back to the main code.

Comment: Note that you aren't changing the type of your object; `datetime.__sub__` is returning an entirely *new* object, based on the original.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention in my answer - are you really wanting to subtract your `tz_offset` (which itself is negative), or is it a negative offset which you then just need to add?

Comment: In conventional terms, US/Eastern is currently UTC-4, so converting from UTC means subtracting the difference in time zones from UTC to get local time.  At least that was what I was thinking when I wrote it.  There is a complimentary method which converts back to UTC where we add the difference instead of subtracting.  It all depends on how you interpret it.

Comment: I wish I could give everyone credit for the very detailed responses to my post.  I went with solution 2c below (at  the end of 2b the way it's shown below) and that is an elegant solution - better than I probably would have done on my own.  Both answers are very good, however.

Comment: Just wanted to note: I use 3 space indents on purpose because it then becomes obvious when a tab character is inserted (8 characters wide).  The only time it wouldn't be obvious is when the indent reaches 24 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important line is this one, within the `to_local()` method:

```
self = self - self.tz_offset
```

Instead of changing `self` (this `worldtime` object) so that it now represents the local time, you are actually setting it to be a completely new object, specifically, the result of `self - self.tz_offset`.

### So why isn't the result of that a `worldtime` object?

Note that the types of object in this calculation are `worldtime` - `timedelta`. At the moment you haven't done anything to specify how to perform subtraction on your `worldtime` class, so `worldtime` automatically inherits its subtraction behavior from its parent class (`datetime`). But this means it gets treated like an ordinary `datetime` object (after all, it *is* really a `datetime`, just with a couple of extra attributes and methods).

So Python carries out a `datetime` - `timedelta` calculation, and the result is a `datetime` object, which it then assigns to `self`. Which is why your `worldtime` object *seems* to be 'changing' into a `datetime`.

### How can we make it work?

There are two options:

**1) Update our object instead of creating a new one**

If we know our offset will always just be some hours, we could do something like:

```py
def to_local(self):
    if self.UTC is True:
        self.hour = self.hour + self.tz_offset.hours
        self.UTC = False
```

**BUT** this **WON'T** work because (contrary to what I initially expected!):

1. `tz_offset` doesn't have a `hours` attribute (when you create a `timedelta` it stores the time as days, seconds and microseconds)
2. `datetime` objects don't let you set the `hour` directly like this

We could try changing the `_hour` attribute (which is how `datetime` stores its time internally), but changing 'private' attributes like this is generally a bad idea. Plus, we still have to turn `tz_offset` back into hours to do that calculation, and what happens if we later want to have an offset with hours *and minutes*? And we need to make sure our offset isn't taking us across a date boundary... (and probably other issues we haven't thought of!)

Better to let `datetime` do what it's good at, so:

**2a) Let `datetime` handle the subtraction, but turn the result back into a `worldtime`**

```py
def to_local(self):
    if self.UTC is True:
        new_time = self - self.tz_offset
        self = worldtime(
            new_time.year,
            new_time.month,
            new_time.day,
            new_time.hour,
            new_time.minute,
            new_time.second,
        )
        self.UTC = False
```

Alternatively, as you mentioned, you could define the `__sub__()` special method to define what the `-` operator does on our `worldtime` objects.

**2b) Override the `-` operator with `__sub__()`**

Let's leave `to_local()` as

```py
def to_local(self):
    if self.UTC is True:
        self = self - self.tz_offset
        self.UTC = False
```

But change how that `-` behaves. Here, we're basically moving what we did in **2a** into a separate method called `__sub__()` (as in **sub**traction). This means that when Python hits the `-`, it passes the left and right operands into the `__sub__()` special method as `self` and `other` (respectively), and then returns the result of the method.

```py
    def __sub__(self, other):
    new_time = self - other
    return worldtime(
        new_time.year,
        new_time.month,
        new_time.day,
        new_time.hour,
        new_time.minute,
        new_time.second,
    )
```

**BUT** when we run this, we get an error like this:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**What happened?**

When Python hits the `self` - `self.tz_offset` in `to_local()`, it calls `__sub__(self, self.tz_offset)`. So far, so good. But when it gets to `self - other` within `__sub__()`, we're still doing subtraction on a `worldtime` object, so Python dutifully calls `__sub__(self, other)` again...and again, and again, and gets stuck in an infinite loop!

We don't want that. Instead, once we're in `__sub__()` we just want to do normal `datetime` subtraction. So it should look like this:

```py
    def __sub__(self, other):
    new_time = super().__sub__(other)
    return worldtime(
        new_time.year,
        new_time.month,
        new_time.day,
        new_time.hour,
        new_time.minute,
        new_time.second,
    )
```

Here, `super().__sub__(other)` means we're using the `__sub__()` method on the parent class instead. Here, that's `datetime`, so we get a `datetime` object back, and can create a new `worldtime` object from that.

---

The whole thing (with your print statements) now looks like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class worldtime(datetime):
    UTC = True
    tz_offset = timedelta(hours = -4)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #kwargs['tzinfo'] = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def is_UTC(self):
        return self.UTC

    def to_local(self):
        print(f"type(self): {type(self)}")
        if self.UTC is True:
            self = self - self.tz_offset
            print(f"type(self): {type(self)}")
            print(self)
            self.UTC = False

    def __sub__(self, other):
        new_time = super().__sub__(other)
        return worldtime(
            new_time.year,
            new_time.month,
            new_time.day,
            new_time.hour,
            new_time.minute,
            new_time.second,
        )


dt = worldtime(2019, 8, 26, 12, 0, 0)
print (f"dt = {dt}   is_UTC(): {dt.is_UTC()}")
print (f"type(dt): {type(dt)}")
print (f"dir(dt): {dir(dt)}")
dt.to_local()
```

(I changed to 4-space tabs, as is standard in Python)

---

### BUT...Is this the best way to do this?

Hopefully that's answered your questions about subclassing in Python.

But reflecting on the problem, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go. Subclassing built-ins can be complicated and easy to get wrong, `datetime`s themselves are already complicated and easy to get wrong. Subclassing `datetime` makes less sense as it's not straightforward to change them after creation, and creating a new object and setting it to `self` doesn't feel very neat.

I wonder if it would be better to use *composition* instead of *inheritance*. So `worldtime` would store a `datetime` object internally, and you can operate on that, and use the timezone support in the `datetime` module to manage your timezone conversion, and maybe just do it on-the-fly for returning the local time.

Something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone


class WorldTime:
    OFFSET = timedelta(hours=-4)

    # assumes input time is in UTC, not local time
    def __init__(self, year, month=None, day=None, hour=0, minute=0, second=0,
                 microsecond=0, tzinfo=timezone.utc, *, fold=0):
        self.dt_in_utc = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second,
                                  microsecond, tzinfo, fold=fold)

    # convert to our timezone, and then make naive ("local time")
    def to_local(self):
        return self.dt_in_utc.astimezone(timezone(self.OFFSET)).replace(tzinfo=None)


dt = WorldTime(2019, 8, 26, 12, 0, 0)
print(dt.to_local())

# Gives:
# 2019-08-26 08:00:00
```

I've made it so that `to_local()` returns a `datetime` object, which you can then print out, or do whatever you want to with afterwards.

---

- This question covers something similar:
  [Convert a python UTC datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-standard-lib)
- This reference is quite good:
  https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python

---

### Edit

I had another experiment with inheriting from `datetime`, and I think the following should work:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone


class WorldTime(datetime):
    OFFSET = timedelta(hours=-4)

    def __new__(cls, *args, tzinfo=timezone.utc, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, tzinfo=tzinfo, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = super().__add__(other)
        return WorldTime(*result.timetuple()[:6], tzinfo=result.tzinfo,
                          fold=result.fold)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        "Subtract two datetimes, or a datetime and a timedelta."
        if not isinstance(other, datetime):
            if isinstance(other, timedelta):
                return self + -other
            return NotImplemented
        return super().__sub__(other)

    def to_local(self):
        return self.astimezone(timezone(self.OFFSET)).replace(tzinfo=None)

dt = WorldTime(2019, 8, 26, 12, 0, 0)
print(dt)
print(dt.to_local())  # local time
print(dt + timedelta(days=20, hours=7))  # 20 days, 7 hours in the future
print(dt - timedelta(days=40, hours=16))  # 40 days, 16 hours in the past
print(dt - WorldTime(2018, 12, 25, 15, 0, 0))  # time since 3pm last Christmas Day


# Output:
# 2019-08-26 12:00:00+00:00  # WorldTime
# 2019-08-26 08:00:00  # datetime
# 2019-09-15 19:00:00+00:00  # WorldTime
# 2019-07-16 20:00:00+00:00  # WorldTime
# 243 days, 21:00:00  # timedelta
```

So it looks like addition and subtraction of `timedelta`s returns a `WorldTime` object, and we can find the difference between two `WorldTime` objects as a `timedelta`.

This isn't rigorously tested, however, so proceed with caution!

Comment: I won't have time today to test this, but I do appreciate the detailed response.  I do want to use the existing subtraction because it will handle date boundaries better than I can do and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I'm not enthusiastic about modules not in the standard library because, in my experience, these things live for years without much maintenance, so finding the equivalent module can become difficult in the future.  Solution 2 is likely what I will  test next.

Comment: I just realised that you can use the timezone functionality provided by the `datetime` module. I don't think it lets you specify timezones by name, but you can do it by a fixed offset. This means that it won't adjust for daylight saving time, but it doesn't rely on a third-party module. I've changed my second example to do that instead. FWIW, I think `pytz` *is* a very reliable and well-maintained library, as it seems to be the de facto standard for timezone support.

Comment: I've had another play around experimenting with inheriting from `datetime`, and think I've made it work for addition and subtraction - see my 'Edit' section at the end of my answer. (I also borrowed m-z's `timetuple()` trick from their answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The result of subtracting (sub-) classes of `datetime` will always return a `datetime` instance. It becomes obvious when taking a look at the implementation for `__add__(self, other)` in the `datetime` module (as `__sub__(self, other)` essentially just forwards the computation to the addition function when subtracting a `timedelta` instance from a `datetime` instance):

```
class datetime(date):

    ...

    def __sub__(self, other):
        "Subtract two datetimes, or a datetime and a timedelta."
        if not isinstance(other, datetime):
            if isinstance(other, timedelta):  # This is True in our case
                return self + -other  # This is calling the __add__ function
            return NotImplemented

        # The remainder of the __sub__ function is omitted as we are 
        # focussing on the case in which a timedelta instance is subtracted 
        # from a datetime instance.

    def __add__(self, other):
        "Add a datetime and a timedelta."
        if not isinstance(other, timedelta):
            return NotImplemented
        delta = timedelta(self.toordinal(),
                          hours=self._hour,
                          minutes=self._minute,
                          seconds=self._second,
                          microseconds=self._microsecond)
        delta += other
        hour, rem = divmod(delta.seconds, 3600)
        minute, second = divmod(rem, 60)
        if 0 < delta.days <= _MAXORDINAL:
            return type(self).combine(date.fromordinal(delta.days),
                                      time(hour, minute, second,
                                           delta.microseconds,
                                           tzinfo=self._tzinfo))
        raise OverflowError("result out of range")
```

The key here is that the `_add__` function creates a new `timedelta` instance, and then uses the `.combine()` function to create a new output.

I'll show you two examples on how you can address this behaviour:

1. **Overwriting the class method `combine(cps, date, time, tzinfo=True)`:**

   ```
   class worldtime

       ...

       @classmethod
       def combine(cls, date, time, tzinfo=True):
           "Construct a datetime from a given date and a given time."
           if not isinstance(date, _date_class):
               raise TypeError("date argument must be a date instance")
           if not isinstance(time, _time_class):
               raise TypeError("time argument must be a time instance")
           if tzinfo is True:
               tzinfo = time.tzinfo
           return cls(date.year, date.month, date.day,
                      time.hour, time.minute, time.second, time.microsecond,
                      tzinfo, fold=time.fold)
   ```

   This should now call the constructor for `worldtime` instead of the parent class `datetime` and return an object of `worldtime`. As the `combine` function is called from many of the existing magic methods it should hopefully cover other cases (and arithmetic operations).
2. **Overwriting the `__sub__(self, other)` method:**

   ```
   class worldtime:

       ...

       def __sub__(self, other):
           # the subtraction will turn sub into an instance of datetime
           # as we‘re calling the original subtraction function of datetime
           sub = super(worldtime, self).__sub__(other)

           # timetuple returns the parameters (year, month, day, etc.) 
           # and we need the first six parameters only to create a new instance.
           return worldtime(*sub.timetuple()[:6])
   ```

   This will convert the difference between `self` and `other` (which has turned into `datetime`) back into an instance of `worldtime` using its constructor.

**The first option is likely to be cleaner as it will be applied to all arithmetic functions of `datetime`.** The second option would require you to add more special cases to other arithmetic operations and may lead to greater implementation and maintenance efforts.

Comment: You showed timedelta's `__sub__` but the relevant one is datetime's `__sub__`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I updated the answer to show the relevant piece of code.

Comment: Overriding `combine()` is a really neat idea, especially because `__add__()` calls `type(self).combine()` so would correctly call the `worldtime` subclass, not just `datetime`.
Just a couple of comments: 1) it's not the *cPython* implementation of `__add__()`, it's just `datetime`'s (which is part of the *standard library*); 2) Your slice on `timetuple` on the last line should be `[:6]` not `[:7]`; 3) You don't really need the arguments in your super call here, you can just call `super()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Tim. I updated my answer with an example of overwritten the `combine` function. The arguments in the `super` call were just to make it more obvious to the OP. I believe the time slice does need to be `[:7]` as we need the first six parameters (year, month, day, hour, minute and second).

Comment: I've realised that, contrary to what we both thought, `datetime.__add__()` *does* actually explicitly call `datetime.combine()`, not just `type(self).combine()`. What you'd copied was `datetime.pyi` (which is the 'interface' file or something for editors/IDEs to use for type checking), rather than `datetime.py`. If you try running a script using that class, it sadly won't work.

Comment: And you're right that we want the first 6 parameters, but Python's slice notation uses 0-indexed half-open intervals, so `[:6]` gives us items `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. You're also getting item `6` (the *7th* item in the list), which for the `struct_time` object returned by `.timetuple()` is the weekday no. (i.e. 0-6, where 0 is Monday). But you're passing it as the 7th positional argument to the `worldtime`, i.e. `datetime` constructor, which is microseconds. So you're accidentally adding a tiny number of microseconds to your `worldtime` instance.