# How to convert a given date, time, and offset into a UTC date time?

Tags: python, time, utc

So I have a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, a time in the format hh:mm:ss AM/PM, and an offset in the format +/-hhmm. These come in a list of these days/time/offset. How can I convert this date and time into a UTC time stamp. For formatting the resulting UTC, I’m assuming I can use string formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a python UTC datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-standard-lib)

Comment: You will need to first use the [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method to parse the data and time strings into a `datetime`, which can changed to that UTC timezone.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to decipher my (somewhat garbled at the end) comment. `;¬)`