# How to convert datetime like `2021-06-25 15:00:08+00:00` to local timezone datetime.datetime python?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have many datetime.datetime object like `2021-06-25 15:00:08+00:00` where the timezone is different for different data.Eg.another data is `2021-06-24 06:33:06-07:00` .I want to save all of them by converting into a local tmezone.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [`datetime.datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) method will return a `datetime` object with the same UTC time but in the local timezone. For your example times:

```
>>> dt_1 = datettime.fromisoformat(2021-06-25 15:00:08+00:00)
>>> dt_1.astimezone()
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 11, 0, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000), 'EDT'))

>>> dt_2 = datetime.fromisoformat(2021-06-24 06:33:06-07:00)
>>> dt_2.astimezone()
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 24, 9, 33, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000), 'EDT'))
```

Since `datetime.datetime` objects with `tzinfo` are timezone-aware, the information will be stored in the objects regardless. This is just a handy way to get the local time.

UPDATE, based on a follow-up question below:

`astimezone()` doesn't depend on the way the `datetime` object is created. For differently formatted date/time strings, [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) can be used to create a timezone-aware `datetime` objects. From the example given in that follow-up question:

```
>>> dt_3 = datetime.strptime('Sat, 26 Jun 2021 15:00:09 +0000 (UTC)',
                             '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
>>> dt_3.astimezone()
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 26, 11, 0, 9, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000), 'EDT'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **pytz** library

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt_input = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-06-24 06:33:06-07:00')
print(dt_input) # prints datetime in input timezone

local_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata') #provide your timezone here
dt_local = dt_input.astimezone(local_tz)

print(dt_local) #prints in your local timezone as provided above
```

You can refer to this SO question similar to your question:

[How to convert a UTC datetime to a local datetime using only standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library)

**EDIT:**
**Convert any string to datetime object:**

You can use **strptime('datestring', 'dateformat')**

example from your comment:

```
#This will convert the string to datetime object    
datetime.strptime('Sat, 26 Jun 2021 15:00:09 +0000 (UTC)','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
```

Once it is converted to datetime object you can convert it to your local timezone as mentioned above

Comment: Hey, Thanks. What about converting Sat, 26 Jun 2021 15:00:09 +0000 (UTC) to datetime.datetime object in local timezone?

Comment: @Prabin if this formatting doesn't work for you then you may refer [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) to look for more formatting options