# Check whether input time falls in given time range in python 3

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me, how to check whether a given time in "hh:mm" format falls in between a given range.
Say, given time is 10:30 A.M IST and my range is between 10:00 A.M and 11:00 A.M. So given time falls in the range.
Is there any package in python to do this in the easiest way?
Would be happy if anyone can help with this :)

Comment: So your given time is given as such a "hh:mm" string? How is the range given?

Comment: The question is like this, say you are running a store, if a person buys an item between 10:00 A.M and 11:00 A.M, 5% discount, if he buys between 11:00 A.M and 12:00 P.M, the 7% discount. Like this, there are many cases in the question.

Comment: So you don't want to tell us. Well, then I can't help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just to use `datetime.time` and compare in an if statement:

```
import datetime

hhmm = "10:30"
current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(hhmm, "%H:%M").time()

if datetime.time(10) <= current_time <= datetime.time(11):
    print("Time is between 10am and 11am")
else:
    print("Time is not between 10am and 11am")
```

The timezone info is removed from the datetime object when `.time()` is called on it - if you input a literal time without a timezone, this isn't an issue, while if you do have a timezone then as long as the datetime is transformed ([via `.astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('IST'))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library)) into the timezone you want, you should just be able to compare with the literal 10am and 11am.

See also [`strptime()` behavior, if your input format is more complicated than the above. It's possible to accommodate for AM/PM, as well as timezone.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)