# How to convert time to different timezone in django python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert time from America/New_York to other(any) timezone using

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

I tried finding references on web but couldn't find it

Comment: TIME_ZONE = 'America/New York' ?

Comment: I assume you don't want the entire project's timezone to change, if you do the above comment will work. If not, you'd just use normal python timezone stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library

Answer (score 0):

Tested it's working modify into settings.py file

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change TIME_ZONE variable in settings.py from utc to ...