# Convert local time to UTC time with zone

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Hello I'm trying to get the UTC time from a local time. How can I proceed?

```py
import datetime as dt
import zoneinfo
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def list_timezones():
    return zoneinfo.available_timezones()

date_str = "Mon, 29 Apr 2019 10:43:55 Asia/Shanghai"

if any((match_tz := tz) in date_str for tz in list_timezones()):
    date_str_nozone = date_str.replace(match_tz, "").strip()
    date_frmt = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"
    naive_time = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str_nozone, date_frmt)
```

`match_tz` extracts the `region/city` from the date string and naive time gives `2019-04-29 10:43:55`.

Now I need to get the UTC offset from `match_tz` and use it on `naive_time` to convert it to UTC time.

I don't want to rely on `pytz` as that is kind of deprecated with recent python versions.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do timezones yourself. You will never get it 100% correct. Instead, use a library to do it for you. If you don't want to use `pytz`, then google for a replacment. A library will do everything for you, so you don't even need to do the `replace()`. Instead, let the library parse the timezone and convert to UTC for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library should be helpful.

Comment: Not trying to do it myself, I think zoneinfo https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html can do it but not sure how to fit it in here

Comment: In particular, I'm referring to the code that calls `replace()` on the timezone. Don't do that. Let python parse the timezone info for you.

Comment: There's no formatter that can parse the region/city format, I have to strip that. It's either +HHHH for %z or %Z which is EST/GMT/UTC etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are making this more difficult than necessary. You should not do any of this logic yourself, not even stripping the timezone from the original string. Instead, leverage existing libraries to do everything for you.

First parse the time stamp string into a datetime:

```
timestamp_local = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str)
```

Then convert the timezone:

```
timestamp_utc = timestamp_local.astimezone(tz=zoneinfo.utc)
```

Then format back to a string when you are ready to display it:

```
print(timestamp_utc.strftime(date_frmt))
```

Be sure to change `date_frmt` to include a formatter for the timezone.

See [How to convert a UTC datetime to a local datetime using only standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library) for more details.

Comment: dt.datetime.strptime(date_str) <- expects a format argument, I can't pass the string with region/city

Comment: @user22881239 I see now. Then my recommendation is to do as you are (maybe you could get the timezone more easily by splitting on white space). Then set the timezone using `replace()` on the datetime. Then change the timezone with `astimezone()`.