Getting daily OHLC prices from hourly data at specific times
In this example I have a dataframe filled with OHLC hourly data from EURUSD.
My strategy revolves around signaling daily patterns and executing on the hourly timeframe. Therefore, besides hourly OHLC data, I also want daily OHLC data.
When criteria is met on the daily, I drop down to the 1 hour to look for an entry
I have tried the following
bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(contract, endDateTime='', durationStr='1 Y', barSizeSetting='1 hour', whatToShow='MIDPOINT', useRTH=True, formatDate=2)

df = pd.DataFrame(bars)[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df['daily open'] = df['open'].resample('D').first()
df['daily close'] = df['close'].resample('D').last()
df['daily high'] = df['high'].resample('D').max()
df['daily low'] = df['low'].resample('D').min()

results dataframe
This does the job relatively well, but the daily OHLC data is calculated at mindnight (00.00). This is UTC time, so a new day starts at 21.15. I tried shifting the entire dataframe, but wondering if that is the best way to do it.
To summarize:

I want the daily close price from the hourly 'close' at 20.00
I want the daily open price from the hourly 'open' at 21.15 previous day
I want the daily high price from 'max' previous day
I want the daily low price from 'low' previous day


Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Is your issue with timezone that open and close market times are not present on same data? If so, then you can apply specific timezone to date. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142704/2847330
