# Apply timezone when convert ms to datetime

Tags: python

Is it possible to apply timezone when parsing ms to datetime?

My parsing is working but it is displaying local time instead of datetime with timezone:

```
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(dt) / 1000.0, 
                                   tz=pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo"))
```

Not sure if it is happening because timezone from my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just parses the timestamp as the tz you provide (so it assumes `dt` is a local time). If `dt` is absolute / UTC and you want to convert it to a local timezone, you need to first parse it it to a UTC datetime *then* move its timezone:

```py
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
```

For instance using [1234567890](https://www.unixtimeconverter.io/1234567890):

```py
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 13, 23, 31, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 13, 21, 31, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' -02-1 day, 22:00:00 DST>)
```

Also note that for various historical reasons properly using pytz is not as simple as that ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422880/pytz-why-is-normalize-needed-when-converting-between-timezones)). If you're going to have to deal with timezones a lot, you may want to take a look at *pendulum* which tries to make timezone manipulations more reliable, and to provide a friendlier API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, it seems to be working as expected. My local time is 09:02 and with the Sao Paolo timezone it shows as 10:02, which seems correct.

```
>>> import datetime, time, pytz
>>> tz_1 = pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")
>>> tz_1
<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' LMT-1 day, 20:54:00 STD>
>>> now = time.time()
>>> now
1554382930.1575696

>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now)
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 9, 2, 10, 157570)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now, tz=tz_1)
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 10, 2, 10, 157570, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' -03-1 day, 21:00:00 STD>)
```

Could you elaborate on which part is not displaying as you expected?