# Datetime timezone conversion adding minute instead of hour offset

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I seem to be having a weird issue. Maybe it's a bug in Python but I would be surprised if it was.

I'm trying to test converting a naive datetime to UTC by first timezone information to it:

```py
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
local_datetime = naive_datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone('Europe/London'))
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
print("Naive datetime:", naive_datetime)
print("Local datetime:", local_datetime)
print("UTC datetime:  ", utc_datetime)
```

This is the output:

```
Naive datetime: 2020-05-14 11:46:44.637956
Local datetime: 2020-05-14 11:46:44.637956-00:01
UTC datetime:   2020-05-14 11:47:44.637956+00:00
```

Note that adding a "Local timezone" of 'Europe/London' adds -1 minute of offset, not +1 hour as I would expect resulting in a "UTC" time of the original time +1 minute not -1 hour.

Why is it adding a minute offset and how do I get this to do what I expect?

Answer (score 3):

don't `replace()` the timezone, `localize()` the datetime object:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# call now() with a tz
local_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone('Europe/London'))

# or localize
naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
tz = timezone('Europe/London')
local_datetime = tz.localize(naive_datetime)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 13, 6, 2, 512100, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' BST+1:00:00 DST>)

# now you can use astimezone to change the tz:
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 12, 6, 2, 512100, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Note: you might also have to `normalize()` if you change between timezones that have DST, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422880/pytz-why-is-normalize-needed-when-converting-between-timezones).

Comment: Thank you. Also good to know about normalize(). I found a solution to change the replace() line to:
```python
local_datetime = naive_datetime.astimezone(timezone('Europe/London'))
```
But I think your localize() solution is clearer as to exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: @OliverP: glad I could help. Note that calling `astimezone` on a naive datetime object will make Python assume that the datetime object belongs in the timezone of the operating system.

Comment: If you feel that the datetime / pytz system is needlessly complicated, check out the `pendulum` library. It's almost identical to datetime, but converting timezones works naturally. It also does a host of other stuff better.

Comment: @JulianIrwin if you want to use the Python standard library only: since Python 3.9, you can [use the zoneinfo module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668778/10197418)